# SQL delete statement for a rowset

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-delete

I need to delete rowset Table 1 (4 row set) by comparing the Table 2 using SQL (`status =Loaded` only) else keep the row-set for that `IG`.

Eg, IG 10 data from TABLE 1 will be deleted and the IG 60 data will be remains same as all the status corresponding to that IG not loaded.

[image]

Comment: Please tag your DBMS product.

Comment: SQL server 2008

Comment: Hi Ankit, can you help please..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following solution. The inner `SELECT` gets all `IG` values which are not successfully loaded. The `DELETE` itself deletes all rows where the `IG` value is not in this list (of unsuccessful loaded) `IG` values.

```
DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE NOT IG IN (
  SELECT IG FROM Table2 WHERE Status <> 'Loaded'
)
```

To make sure you delete the right rows you can use the following `SELECT` first:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE NOT IG IN (
  SELECT IG FROM Table2 WHERE Status <> 'Loaded'
)
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ffafb8a131aaaa3d86563de44f017bfe)

Comment: Thanks, but i think this will delete only individual rows ..I need to delete the row set that means every rows having IG10.. and keep all the rows having IG60.

Comment: This is exactly what this query does. You can use the `SELECT` to check.

Comment: Great, it seems to be perfect except the NOT IG IN , I think the NOT would not needed to mentioned.. as my goal is to delete the IG60 combinations.

Comment: sorry @Sebastian Brosch some confusion happened with the select ( I though the select as delete),  your code is perfect. Thanks a ton, you saved my life :) good day

Answer (score 1):

Use [NOT IN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) clause :

```
delete from TB1 where not IG in  (
  select IG from TB2 where status <> 'Loaded'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
delete From [TABLE 1]
where IG in
(
Select IG from [TABLE 2] a where not exists(Select 1 From [TABLE 2] b where a.IG  = b.IG and Status not in ('Loaded') )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query

```
DELETE FROM TABLE1 WHERE IG NOT IN (SELECT IG FROM TABLE2 WHERE STATUS = 'ERROR')
```

Comment: this might be a problem because if there a record with a status different from Error and Loaded, they will be deleted too.